# Receiving aliased fields based on request to wagtail REST API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

Suppose I have a model with the following fields:

```
class SomePage(Page):
    other_fields = ...
    field_en = models.CharField(max_length=280, blank=False, null=False)
    field_de = models.CharField(max_length=280, blank=False, null=False)
    field_zh = models.CharField(max_length=280, blank=False, null=False)
```

Where every `_lang` is the field translated into a certain language. (Their number is known in advance since they're not likely to change in the future)

When I use Wagtail's REST API, the responses come including all fields, and I have to start excluding fields manually:

```
{
  <other fields>: ...
  "field_en": ...
  "field_de": ...
  "field_zh": ...
}
```

So, this can be solved by excluding the fields I don't want, however I would like to, ideally, either request them with a `?lang=en` parameter, and receive cleaner replies such as:

```
{
  <other fields>: ...
  "field": ... // This is actually field_en!
}
```

So that my frontend or any other client doesn't have to implement the `field_<lang>` logic.

As a sidenote - the built-in field `title` in page might also get translated, which means there'll be `title`, `title_de` and `title_zh` for example, which might require some extra logic.

I dug around in `BaseEndpoint` and have been able to create a class to generate `_lang`-specific endpoints when subclassed, but it would return `field_<lang>` rather than `field` as well as being a little ugly (have to subclass it once per language and register them separately, yuck)

Appreciate any help or pointers :)

Comment: Look at [django-modeltranslation](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Either use that or look at the source code to see how it's done.